# Using ggplot to create a histogram or barplot of a dataset with separate one-hot encoded columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

Ok, I have a dataset with two categorical variables that I want to plot on a histogram or barplot.  I'd like to do this to verify my suspicions that the two categories are not of equal proportions.  This is key because I'm trying to develop a classifier, and I'll need to know how disproportionate the categories are in order to decide whether to use an under sampling or over sampling method (or some combination of both).

The table looks something like this:

| ID | Category1 | Category2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |

...and so on for several thousand rows.

Obviously I cannot daisy chain a bunch of ggplot functions to this as is, since for a histogram or barplot I could only directly specify one column.  I've tried using gather(), but I don't think I understand how it's concept of key-values work and how to use that to squish the columns together.  Even if I could, it would just results in a bunch of ones and zeroes, and that doesn't directly compute to an accurate representation of categories since effectively there are many samples where neither Category 1 or Category 2 exists, effectively giving me a Category 3 for "Unknown".

How do I take these two columns and derive a single column that tells me whether each sample is Category 1, Category 2, or Category 3 (for unknown), so that I can plot this using ggplot?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following is close to what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar()
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(ID = 0:5, Category1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L
), Category2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could first use `pivot_longer` to bring data in right format:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("Cat"),
        names_to = "Category",
        values_to = "values"
    ) 

ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(Category), fill=factor(values))) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

data:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
       Category1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
       Category2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I hesitated in setting argument `position = "dodge"` and chose not to, for no special reason. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your responses.  I didn't realize that pivot_longer() had been added as a possible tool until now, so this has been extremely informative.

Ultimately, I realized that if I was coding this as a for loop over every row in Python, my "lazy solution" would've been to use an ifelse() statement.  And then I had a thought: what if I just used mutate() in conjunction with R's ifelse() instead of using gather() or pivot_longer() to get the desired result?

```
ggplot(data = 
    my_df %>% 
    select(Category1, Category2) %>% 
    mutate(METHOD = ifelse(Category1 == 1, "Category1",
        ifelse(Category2 == 1, "Category2", "NONE"))),
    aes(x = METHOD, fill = METHOD)
) + 
    geom_bar()
```